# Empty typescript file with the script command

Tags: command-line

In the command line, I typed:

```
script -a myfile
```

Then, I typed the some standard commands.

When I opened the `myfile` using `vi`, the file was empty. Why is that?
And, also, any tips on using the `ttyrec` and `ttyplay` commands?

Comment: Did you exit the shell before viewing the file?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your implementation of script is flushing the output by default. If it available, try this:

```
script -f -a myfile
```

That said, I would suggest that you use ***more*** or ***less*** commands to view the file. In fact, you probably want to view that file in a separate login session, as your vi/more/less session will be flushed to the file in realtime.